# Rails Counter Cache and its implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to get hold of rails counter cache feature but not able to grasp it completely.

Let's say that We have 3 models

A B C

A belongs to B or C depending upon a field key_type and key_id. key_type tells whether A belongs to B or C so if key_type="B" then the record belongs to B otherwise it belongs to C.

In my model a.rb, I have defined following associations:

```
belongs_to :b, :counter_cache => true, :foreign_key => "key_id"
belongs_to :c, :counter_cache => true, :foreign_key => "key_id"
```

and

in b and c model files

```
has_many :as , :conditions => {:key_type => "B"}
has_many :as , :conditions => {:key_type => "C"}
```

Both B and C Models have a column as as_count

The problem is every time an object of a is created count is increased in the both the models b and c.

Any help is appreciated. Initially i thought that this may work:

```
belongs_to :b, :counter_cache => true, :foreign_key => "key_id", :conditions => {:key_type => "B"}
belongs_to :c, :counter_cache => true, :foreign_key => "key_id", :conditions => {:key_type => "C"}
```

But this does not help.

Thanks

Comment: This should not be tagged with "grails".

Answer (score 15):

It looks like polymorphic associations are the way to go for your issue.

Imagine you have a Comment model and 2 models which can be commented : Post and Profile.

In Post and Profile models :

```
has_many :comments, :as => :resource
```

In Comment model :

```
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
```

Don't forget to add the "comments_count" column in both Profile and Post models and voilà !

Comment: It's only working when adding comments. The comments_count increases but when a comment is deleted it won't update comments_count. any idea why this might be happening? any possible solution? Thank You.

Comment: looks like there's a bug with counter_cache and polymorphic relationships in rails < 5.0. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16407

Answer (score 4):

See http://blog.locomotivellc.com/post/4120559953/counter-cache-polymorphism for a demo.